# How to save image url from Firebase storage to realtime databse using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I was able to get the downloadURL of the image but i need to save it to my realtime database. Please help. Here is the code that i tried.

```
const storageRef = sRef(storage, 'images/' + 'announcement/');

const file_ann = document.getElementById("image_ann").files[0];
const name_ann = file_ann.name;

const metadata_ann = {
    contentType: file_ann.type
}

const uploadAnnouncement = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file_ann, metadata_ann);

getDownloadURL(uploadAnnouncement.snapshot.ref).then((announcementURL) => {
    console.log('File available at', announcementURL);
})

const announcementimg = document.getElementById("image_ann").value;

set(ref(database, 'page-content/' + 'announcement/'), {
    announcementimg: announcementURL,
})

.then(() => {
 window.alert("Announcement Updated!");
})
.catch((error) => {
 window.alert("Error!");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the download URL is (like most modern cloud API calls) an asynchronous operation. This means that any code that needs the `announcementURL` has to be inside the `then()` block that is called when that URL is available.

So:

```
getDownloadURL(uploadAnnouncement.snapshot.ref).then((announcementURL) => {
    console.log('File available at', announcementURL);

    const announcementimg = document.getElementById("image_ann").value;
    
    set(ref(database, 'page-content/' + 'announcement/'), {
        announcementimg: announcementURL,
    })
    .then(() => {
     window.alert("Announcement Updated!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
     window.alert("Error!");
    });
})
```